# Export Linear Mixed Effects Model Outputs in csv using Julia Language

Tags: julia, mixed-models

I am new to `Julia` programming language, however, I am fitting a `Linear Mixed Effects Model` and I find it difficult to save the `fixed` and `random` effects estimates in `.csv` files.

**An example code can be found:**

```
using MixedModels
@time modelOutput = fit(lmm(Y~ A + B + (0 + A | group), data))
```

There is available reference about how to obtain the fixed (`fixef(modelOutput)`) and random (`ranef(modelOutput)`) effects however using a DataFrame I am facing errors.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Could you give details on your error, and a minimum reproducible example? Generally, `writetable("output.csv", df)` should write your data to a csv file, given that it is in a DataFrame. However, from the [MixedModels.jl](https://github.com/dmbates/MixedModels.jl) GitHub page I gather that the output of `ranef(m)` is actually a simple Array, not a DataFrame, so what does your question have to do with DataFrames?

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I am correct, random effects are arrays without information about the groups of the random coefficient estimates. I also used the option `coeftable(modelOutput)` in order to pass it into a `writetable` however I am getting the following error:  **writetable has no method matching writetable(::ASCIIString, ::CoefTable)**

Comment: That's because a `CoefTable` is not a `DataFrame` - as the name would suggest. I'm not familiar with `RandomModels.jl`, but it shouldn't be hard to get the entries of your coeftable into a Dataframe.

Comment: I tried to pass coeftable into a `DataFrame` and it failed as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I actually took the time to do this for you. A `CoefTable` is a type defined in `statmodels` [here](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl/blob/7003962de11031e1df182045e9391f6120a85f3e/src/statmodels.jl#L27). Given this information, we can extract the relevant information from the `CoefTable` instance as follows:

```
df = DataFrame(variable = ct.rownms,
               Estimate = ct.mat[:,1],
               StdError = ct.mat[:,2],
               z_val = ct.mat[:,3])
```

This will give an nvar-by-4 `DataFrame` which you can then write to csv as described earlier using `writetable("output.csv",df)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is a very informative approach. The 5th column does not work for some reason. Actually I am getting the following: `coeftable(fitModelREML).mat[:,4]`    **ERROR: BoundsError()
 in checkbounds at abstractarray.jl:62 (repeats 2 times)**. Is there an equivalent way to export results of random effects?

Comment: Well, as the error says, you're accessing the coeftable out of bounds. As I don't know what model you're fitting exactly, I don't know what's inside your coeftable, but you can find out yourself by simply doing `coeftable(fitModelREML).mat` and checking the dimensions of the resulting matrix. Maybe there's no p-value column in your table, then you could just get rid of the entire `Pr_z = ct.mat[:,4]` line in my answer.

Btw, if an answer at Stackoverflow solved your problem, you should accept it using the green tick mark to mark this for future reference.

Comment: I've edited the code accordingly, it appears that the `lmm` model only outputs three columns (Estimate, Std Error, and z-value)

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. Is there any way to obtain the random effects also?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MixedModels, but from the docs it appears that you can extract them using `ranef(m)`, where `m` is the fitted model. `ranef` will just return an array of floats.

Comment: I'm getting "ERROR: type CoefTable has no field mat" when I try to do this with julia version 0.5.2, StatsBase 0.17 ... I ended up using `ct.cols[1]` and so forth instead of `ct.mat[:,1]` ...

Answer (score 2):

I had a  number of problems getting the accepted answer to work; Julia has evolved a lot since then. I rewrote it based primarily on code from the [jglmm R package](https://github.com/mikabr/jglmm), with some adaptation/cobbling-together from other sources ...

```
"""
    outfun(m, outfn="output.csv")

output the coefficient table of a fitted model to a file
"""
outfun = function(m, outfn="output.csv")
    ct = coeftable(m)
    coef_df = DataFrame(ct.cols);
    rename!(coef_df, ct.colnms, makeunique = true)
    coef_df[!, :term] = ct.rownms;
    CSV.write(outfn, coef_df);
end
```